# What does enough damage to out-damage Zenyatta's Transendance?

Tags: overwatch

I was playing Zenyatta and a Junkrat ult killed a few people inside it. I was wondering what other attacks/abilities/moves in the game can do enough damage to outright kill, or outdamage zenyatta's healing? Assuming it's being used on a character of 200 health (which is the mode health)

Comment: Do you realize that RIP-tire deals a single instance of damage instead of steady damage per second?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Of Course I'm aware of that. The point of the question is that it can kill someone while in transcendence, while for example, a steady stream of mei's primary fire will not. That's what the question is asking. _what other attacks/abilities/moves in the game can do enough damage to outright kill, or outdamage zenyatta's healing?_ Which JR's rip-tire. _Can_ do.

Comment: @BritishFerret: I think the question is wierd. "Which single instant thing does enough damage to outdamage zenyattas healing over time?" Presumably virtually every attack in the game does. Even if you focus on killing, it's nearly identical to "which attacks can outright kill?", and thus unrelated to healing...

Comment: @mooing duck yes, the title was phrased oddly, but I feel this:  _I was wondering what other attacks/abilities/moves in the game can do enough damage to outright kill, or outdamage zenyatta's healing?_ clarrifies it well. Regardless of how it was worded, people looked over semantics and gave a well researched answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zenyatta's ultimate ability, Transcendence, heals [300 health per second](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zenyatta#Transcendence), which is faster than any other individual damage-over-time ability in the game (such as Hanzo's Dragonstrike or Pharah's Barrage). This makes him very strong against certain "wombo combos".

However, Zenyatta's Transcendence does not grant any bonus health to people within the ultimates radius, meaning that if they take enough instantaneous damage, they can still be killed. Junkrat's RIP-Tire, for example, does 600 damage - plenty to take out any non-tank character. D.Va's Self-Destruct also does enough damage to kill anybody. The only person left standing would be the invulnerable Zenyatta.

These are the abilities that will guarantee killing **any** character being healed by Zenyatta Transcendence:

- D.Va's Self-Destruct
- McCree's Deadeye (full charge)

These are the abilities that will kill **lower health** characters (Any DPS/support class plus some defense characters):

- Pharah's Barrage (assuming 10 of the 30 rockets per second hit a single target)
- Junkrat's RIP-Tire (can also kill Roadhog and Zarya)
- Widowmaker's fully charged scoped headshot
- Hanzo's fully charged headshot
- Hanzo's scatter arrow
- Reinhardt's pin damage from Charge
- Doomfist's charged punch, if enemy hits a wall
- Tracer's Pulse Bomb
- Bastion's Configuration: Tank
- Doomfist's Meteor Strike

Other ways to kill people while they are in Transcendence:

- Bastion's Configuration: Sentry can do 525 damage per second, which *does* out-damage Zenyatta's healing. It's a little unreliable though, since it requires perfect accuracy (difficult in a hectic team fight, not to mention his increased spread). Also, he has trouble when people are in front of his desired target - your target will have time to get fully healed again by the time the blocker has stepped out of the way.
- Displacement works well since it can force people out of Zenyatta's Transcendence. Roadhog's Chain Hook, Pharah's Concussive Blast, Lucio's Soundwave, Junkrat's Concussion Mine - anything that separates Zenyatta from his team will leave them vulnerable. Alternatively, use displacement moves to knock the Zenyatta out of bounds - it's the only way to kill him while he's using his ultimate.
- Despite the visible indicator, Zenyatta's ult (and other similar AoE skills) work by line of sight, which means that attacking someone who can't see their allied Zenyatta will deal regular damage and they won't heal. Mei's ice wall works well to separate Zenyatta from his team.
- Ana's grenade prevents healing from any source when it hits an enemy. This makes Ana a fantastic counter to a Zenyatta.

Note that this list does not include "wombo combos", though it is possible to chain ults together - using Zarya's Graviton Surge, Hanzo's Dragonstrike, and Reaper's Death Blossom at the same time might do the trick, for example.

It also does not include damage buffs such as Ana's Nano Boost, Mercy's Caduceus Staff damage boost, or Orb of Discord - all of which can help push a lot of other abilities over the 300 damage threshold to instantly kill someone under the effect of Transcendence.

Comment: A note about Pharah's barrage: While it does deal its damage over time, its dps is 1200, provided all rockets hit, so as long as a large enough percentage are hitting Zenyatta's healing targets, the damage will outpace the healing.

Comment: Also on enemies with extremely low health like tracer or a DVa without her mech a direct hit from Pharah or Junkrat might kill them.

Comment: @MichaelMcDevitt The rockets have a wide spread though so it's practically impossible that they all hit the same target.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Indeed. In fact, pretty much the only way to get hit by all the rockets is to stand right in front of Pharah as she ults... but since she'll also take splash damage from the rockets, she'll die before firing everything off. If you have no other defenses, having a D.Va fly right into an ulting Pharah will usually kill Pharah while D.Va lives with around 300 health. (I've done this, it's quite amusing)

Comment: Bastion deals 525 damage per second (!!!) while deployed as a sentry, and can headshot on top of that (1050 damage per second with perfect accuracy). Surely that's enough damage over time to overcome 300 hp/second of healing.

Comment: (Also Reinhardt's charge should do enough burst damage to kill low-health heroes instantly).

Comment: @MageXy That is indeed quite amusing.

Comment: @MageXy Alternatively, you can just absorb all the rockets with defense matrix.

Comment: So in summary, adding to this:
- Pharah's barrage maybe from a closeish range, but not too close
-  Bastion in Turret mode (especially with headshots) 

However:
Pharah direct hits do 120 damage, and only fire every 1.1 seconds, so it'd be impossible to overcome + 300 a second.
Junkrat direct hits do 120 damage, and only fire every 1.6 seconds, so again, impossible. Unless it was combo'd with his Shift mine, which does 120. So if combo'd _really_ fast. Or the mine activated as the bomb direct hits. It would deal 240 damage. Enough to get our theoretical 200 health character

Comment: @WolfieeifloW Sorry, I was editing my post and seem to have accidentally rejected yours. It was a good edit though, please resubmit it and I will approve it.

Comment: Speaking of Ana, don't forget that you can obviously cancel out that 300 hp/second by throwing a grenade at your target of choice, allowing yourself (or an ally) to deal damage with full impunity

Comment: Yes this is from a while ago but I am new and had some more input... Rein pin damage to kill someone in Zen ult is assuming 2 things. That he is hitting them at full speed/potential damage and that he is dragging them outside of the ult.

Comment: @n_palum I don't think that's the case - the charge does 300 damage to the pinned hero (only 50 to "bumped" heroes) when they hit a wall, regardless of the distance travelled/speed of impact. That's more than enough to OHKO the squishier DPS heroes, even in a Zen ult.

Comment: Hmm fair point.. but does that mean rein charge is assuming bump status if he pins them and they collide in too short of a span?

Comment: @n_palum The way Rein charge works is the first hero that is standing directly in front of the charge will be caught in the pin. That hero will take the full 300 damage if a wall is hit, or none if the charge ends (either through a stun or just travelling too far). If a hero is hit by a Reinhardt that has already pinned someone in the charge, or if Reinhardt hits a hero at an angle, that hero will instead take only 50 damage and be knocked back. Distance traveled is not important in either case.

Answer (score -2):

So with Zen his healing is done per second, so last patch I remember it was 300HP a second recovery.

Junkrat's RIP-tire deals 600 damage

Tracer's Pulse Bomb deals 400 damage

These two I believe are the only ones who can out damage as they are burst damage in a second and it's instant rather than over time like reaper or phara which can be counter healed.